# Why Does My C Binary to Decimal Program Not Return the Correct Value?

Tags: c, return-value

For part of a larger assignment, I'm writing a program that converts a binary number to a decimal. I know the way I'm doing it is kind of weird and could probably be improved upon, but I like the way it is now, and it almost works. The only problem is that if you feed it 10 as your binary number, it returns 1, but it should return 2. All other numbers I tested work correctly. Here's the relevant part of code:

```
int countDigits (int num) {
    int digits = 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        num /=10;
        digits++;
    }
    return digits;
}

long int binToDec (int num) {
    int numDigits = countDigits(num);
    char temp[32];
    int numStore[32];
    long int sum = 0;
    snprintf(temp, 32, "%d", num);
    for (int i = 0; i < numDigits; i++) {
        numStore[i] = temp[i] - '0';
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numDigits; i++) {
        if (numStore[i] == 1) {
            sum += pow(2, i);
        }
    }
    printf("%ld\n", sum);
    return sum;

}

int main(void) {
    binToDec(10);
    return 0;
}
```

I absolutely can't figure out why it's not returning the proper value. At first I thought I was iterating in the wrong order, but unless I did it incorrectly, counting i down instead of up produced the same output. Could someone point out my error?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to step through the program, so you can examine variables at each step?

Comment: Because You Used `2^i` Where You Should Have Used `2^(numDigits-1-i)` Since You Go in Reverse.

Comment: "I know the way I'm doing it is kind of weird" -- what an understatement.  You reinterpret the decimal representation of a number as a binary representation of a different number, which is *bizarre*.  It doesn't even make sense for the majority of possible argument values.

Comment: Supposing that this is an academic assignment, I suspect that you have missed the point.  The usual expectation for such an exercise is that you will convert a decimal digit *string* to a binary digit *string*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I wouldn't be surprised if the assignment gave this exact prototype for `binToDec`, or at least stated that it should work with integers.

Comment: @Nelxiost, I would be very surprised if the prototype were specified as presented in the question, but it is pointless to speculate.

Comment: @Nelxiost If the assignment specified the prototype, it would be `int foo(long)` not `long foo(int)`, since the (decimal) output value is necessarily more compact than the bizarre binary-as-decimal input value.

Comment: @user3386109 Why would you assume the correctness of such a bad assignment in the first place ?

Comment: @Nelxiost There's nothing wrong with the assignment. The only thing wrong is OP's bizarre approach to the assignment.

Comment: So to answer a few questions: 1. This in itself is not the assignment. We were left to determine how to do this on our own. This is just necessary for representing other parts of the assignment. The reason I did it the way I did is that I tried to represent in code how I would work this out manually; count how many numbers you are into the binary string, and if it's a 1, raise two to the power of the index, then sum.

Comment: @Nelxiost's solution works, so thanks for pointing out the flaw in my logic. And again, I'm aware there are far more efficient and sane ways to do this, I just wanted to do it in a way I could visualize more easily.

Comment: I want to reiterate that this is not the heart of the assignment; it's just a function I'll need for later. Also, why would I go back if what I have almost works? If I completely redid my functions every time something didn't give me an expected value, I'd never get done.

Comment: But, if you presented the original assignment, and asked for advice on how best to approach the problem, you may find that the solution can be written as 10 lines of code where you are writing 100. The 37 people that have viewed your question easily have a combined 500 years of experience writing C code.  You've thrown that knowledge away. But the choice is yours, and you have made that choice. I accept that.

Comment: I do appreciate the advice, but this really is a much smaller part of the work than you seem to be thinking. This didn't take too long to write, and the only part I got stuck on was where my logic was mistaken, which someone was kind enough to point out. I understand and agree that I did it in a very obtuse, overly-complicated way, but as long as it's not causing me issues I have no motivation to change it.

Answer (score 1):

I like the pointless but fun *decimal coded binary* (DCB) representation but you way over engineered this.  Consider using the logic in your `countDigits()` function as the basis for `binToDec()` and you get something much simpler like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

unsigned int binToDec(unsigned long number) {
    unsigned int sum = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; number > 0; i++, number /= 10) {
        if (number % 2 != 0) {
            sum += pow(2, i);
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

int main(void) {

    printf("%u\n", binToDec(101010));

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> ./a.out
42
> dc
2 i
101010 p
42
>
```

and an input of `10` gives you an output of `2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I haven't learned or used bit-shifting before, and I'd rather not use operators I don't know in my implementation.

Comment: @Kurausukun, simple enough to fix, swapped out `1 << i` and substituted `pow(2, i)` which you used in your original code.